# Best way to create a new thread from an async method in python

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, pycord

I'm currently writing a discord bot which needs to be able to run a task that could take anywhere from a few seconds to a minute while still being responsive to other commands. Forgive me if this is a fairly simple question, but I haven't been able to find a solution that worked yet.

Here is an abridged version of the code

```
class StableCog(commands.Cog, name='Stable Diffusion', description='Create images from natural language.'):
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.text2image_model = Text2Image()
    self.bot = bot

@commands.slash_command(description='Create an image.')
async def dream(self, -- a ton of arguments -- ):
    print(f'Request -- {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator} -- Prompt: {query}')
    asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(src.bot.queue_system.dream_async( -- a ton of arguments -- ))
```

inside queue_system.py

```
async def dream_async(-- a ton of arguments --):
await ctx.interaction.response.send_message('Added to queue! You are # in queue')
embed = discord.Embed()
try:
    #lots of code, I've removed it since it doesn't have anything to do with the async
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed, file=discord.File(fp=buffer, filename=f'{seed}.png'))

except Exception as e:
    embed = discord.Embed(title='txt2img failed', description=f'{e}\n{traceback.print_exc()}', color=embed_color)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

However, the discord bot becomes unresponsive until the code in queue_system.py finishes running. Every solution I've tried so far hasn't worked correctly since I'm trying to create a thread to run an asynchronous method. What would be the best way to do so? Ignore the name `queue_system.py`, it isn't quite a queue system yet, I'm just working out how to run the dream method asynchronously before I work that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is blocking the event loop in the *dream_async* coroutine ? In that coroutine  if you're calling some (non async) functions that have the potential to block the loop, that's an issue, but the real culprit must be in the "lots of code" part :)

A good option would be to use [run_in_executor()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to run the non async code in a threadpool, and therefore prevent that code from blocking *dream_async*.

```py
def blocking_stuff(arg):
    # this will run in a thread
    ...
    
    return 'something'


async def dream_async(-- a ton of arguments --):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    await ctx.interaction.response.send_message('Added to queue! You are # in queue')
    embed = discord.Embed()

    try:
        # Run the blocking part in a threadpool
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_stuff, 'test') 

        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed, file=discord.File(fp=buffer, filename=f'{seed}.png'))

    except Exception as e:
        embed = discord.Embed(title='txt2img failed', description=f'{e}\n{traceback.print_exc()}', color=embed_color)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Hope i didn't misunderstand you.

Comment: I ended up solving this issue by creating an async method that started a thread to do all of the stuff that was blocking (using an AI to generate an image). Looks like using `run_in_executor` would've done more or less the same thing, although I needed to be able to check if the thread was alive at any time. Looks like this would have worked great though if I had seen it in time! The actual code is here in case you are curious https://github.com/harubaru/discord-stable-diffusion/pull/6/commits/b2c9c1c4d219e02ec0fa3cae2d95c83ccdec900b

Comment: Saw the commit, I think your implementation with the *dream_thread* is good and adapted to your use case, personally i don't like to directly use the *Thread* API in an asyncio program. There's another way to implement what you want with little changes, by using an asyncio Queue and an async task, which will read the items on the queue, and for each item, call *await run_in_executor(pool, handle_item, item)* for each item. I'll post an example later on.